# _co.userData is undefined ionic 3

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3, undefined, angularjs-ng-model

I am getting Error for the ngModel.

_co.userData is not defined.

I have posted my home.ts and home.html file.
browser console showing the error is near [(ngModel)].

This is my home.ts file

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AuthService} from '../../providers/auth-service/auth-service';
import { CompanygroupsPage } from '../companygroups/companygroups';




@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
responseData:any;
userData:{"username":"hi","password":"123"}

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public authService:AuthService){}
login(){
console.log(this.userData);
this.navCtrl.push(CompanygroupsPage);
}


}
```

This is my home.html file

```
<ion-content padding class="home">
<ion-list class="login">
  <form>
    <ion-item class="inputs">
        <ion-label stacked>Username</ion-label>
        <ion-input value="" type="text" [(ngModel)]="userData.username" name="username"></ion-input>
        <ion-icon name="contact" item-left></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item class="inputs">
        <ion-label stacked>Password</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="password" value="" [(ngModel)]="userData.password" name="password"></ion-input> 
        <ion-icon name="lock" item-left></ion-icon>

      </ion-item>
      <button (click)="login()" class="btn_login"  ion-button color="light" round>Login</button>
    </form>
    </ion-list>  
  <ion-footer class="footer">
      <ion-toolbar>
       ...
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-footer>
```

Error is near

```
<ion-input value="admin" type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" name="username"></ion-input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign,

Change

**From**

```
userData:{"username":"hi","password":"123"}
```

**To**

```
userData = {"username":"hi","password":"123"}
```

Comment: OMG !!Solved ! Thanks a alot .. :)

Comment: @DineshHebbar FYI the `:` is to specify data type not value.

Comment: Accepted !! Thank You.